# Time complexity for generating all possible topological sorts of a graph

Tags: time-complexity, graph-theory, topological-sort

I was going through the solution to find and print all the topological sorts of a directed acyclic graph using backtracking with kahn sorting.

Complete solution is here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/all-topological-sorts-of-a-directed-acyclic-graph/

According to me, the time complexity of this solution would be O(V!) where V = total vertex of graphs. Worst case would be V disconnected vertices. In that case, in each ith recursion we would be traversing (i-1) vertices with in-degree as 0. Total number of topological sorts = O(V!) in that case.

Can you please help me with the time complexity of the solution? Would it be O(V!)?

Comment: Do you want to find/display all solutions, or just count them? In the first case, the complexity cannot be lower than the number of solutions

Comment: I want to print all the solutions (not just count).

Comment: You’re right that this problem strongly recommends an output-sensitive analysis.